# WordPress equivalent of Drupal's url()

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, url-rewriting

Is there any WordPress equivalent function for Drupal's [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/url/6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for the drupal function I think the closest thing you're gonna find is site_url().

```
/**
 * Retrieve the site url for the current site.
 *
 * Returns the 'site_url' option with the appropriate protocol,  'https' if
 * is_ssl() and 'http' otherwise. If $scheme is 'http' or 'https', is_ssl() is
 * overridden.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @since 2.6.0
 *
 * @uses get_site_url()
 *
 * @param string $path Optional. Path relative to the site url.
 * @param string $scheme Optional. Scheme to give the site url context. Currently 'http','https', 'login', 'login_post', or 'admin'.
 * @return string Site url link with optional path appended.
*/
site_url(string path, string scheme);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the file `link-template.php` in `wp-includes`.

It's full of useful URL functions! (also check out `category-template.php` for `get_category_link()` and `get_tag_link()`).